# Looking for a proof that if a normal subgroup of $Sym(\mathbb N)$ has an element of infinite order then it is the whole group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

I know that $Sym (\mathbb N)$ , the group of all permutations on $\mathbb N$ , has exactly two non-trivial normal subgroups and both of these subgroups are torsion , so it follows that if a normal subgroup of $Sym(\mathbb N)$ has an element of infinite order then it is the whole group . But I am looking for a simpler way to prove that "if a normal subgroup of $Sym(\mathbb N)$ has an element of infinite order then it is the whole group " without having to go through determining all the normal subgroups of $Sym(\mathbb N)$ . Is it possible ? I can get that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $Sym(\mathbb N)$ containing an element of infinite order then $N$ contains an element of order $2$ with exactly countably infinitely many two-cycles and countably infinitely many fixed points . Is this fact any important in proving a simple way my required statement ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you are aware of the fact that are two different kinds of elements of infinite order: those with an infinite cycle and those having only finite cycles, but without bound on their lengths.

Answer (score 1):

My comment wasn't quite right, so I will try again.

By considering the standard permutation representation of a (finite or infinite) dihedral group in which a point stabilizer is a reflection, we see that any finite or infinite cycle can be written as the product of two involutions (i.e. elements of order $2$). So, by decomposing an arbitrary permutation $h$ of ${\mathbb N}$ as a product of cycles, it follows that $h$ is the product of two involutions.

Now, if $g$ is an involution in  ${\rm Sym}({\mathbb N})$ with infinitely many transpositions and fixed points, then any involution in $G$ is either conjugate to $g$ or, if it has only finitely many transpostions or fixed points, a product of two conjugates of $g$. It follows than any $h \in {\mathbb N}$ is the product of at most four conjugates of $g$.

Comment: how to show that if an involution  has only finitely many transpostions or fixed points, a product of two conjugates of $g$? could you please elaborate .. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, for example, the fixed point free involution $(0,1)(-1,-2)(2,3)(-3,-4)(4,5)(-5,-6) \cdots$ is the product of the conjugates $(0,1)(2,3)(4,5) \cdots$ and $(-1,-2)(-3,-4)(-5,-6) \cdots$ of $g$.

Comment: sorry to bring it back again ... but could you please explain the general procedure of showing that if an involution has only finitely many transpositions or fixed points, a product of two conjugates of $g$ ?

Comment: or any reference may be ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's clear from the example how to do it in general. I am a little puzzled, because this all seems much easier than showing that an normal subgroup that contains an element of infinite order contains an involution with infinitely many fixed points and transpositions, but you have managed to do that!